# Lock screen (similar to pressing power button) on Android using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm creating an app and wanted to programmatically lock the device once the user taps a button.

I've searched online about this and the only stuff I found was lock screen orientation or some APIs to create a Lock-screen app.

I just wondering if a simple thing like `thisDevice.lock();` or `AndroidStuff.powerMgmt.lockScreen();`. I mean, seems too basic and essential but I just can't find it

Comment: check kiosk mode - https://snow.dog/blog/kiosk-mode-android suspect I mean it

Comment: Well kiosk mode might allow for it, but it's an weird solution and not desirable for a regular app. I just want a option to lock the device like when you tap on the lock button on the notification bar (some devices don't have it). Thanks for you suggestion anyway